# Get-MgUser accountEnabled

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I need the accountenabled property to further the script, but for `Get-MgUser`.

I need to modify the current script that have Msol or AzureAD cmdlets to MSGraph, but I can't find anything so i don't throw out the script and create a new one.

```
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$UserPrincipalName'" | select ObjectId, AccountEnabled
```

Comment: You mean `Get-MgUser -Filter 'accountEnabled eq true' -All` to get all enabled users or `Get-MgUser -Filter 'accountEnabled eq false' -All` to get the disabled users? There's also the `-Property` parameter where you can set it to `AccountEnabled` to have that returned

Answer (score 0):

In order to get he users with account enabled in microsoft graph check the following:

***`Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -AllowClobber -Force`***

**`Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'User.Read.All'`**

- The following property must be used with filter im Microsft graph as by default its not present in commandlets:

***`Get-MgUser -Filter 'accountEnabled eq true' -All`***

**Result:**

```
Id                                   DisplayName                                           Mail                                           UserPrincipalName                       
--                                   -----------                                           ----                                           -----------------                       
xx09e Admin                                                 adminxxOnMicrosoft.com
```

It doesn't have the particular property account enabled but can be filtered

[image] x

**Reference:** [Get-MgUser (Microsoft.Graph.Users) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0)

In azure ad commandlets we get those properties :

**`Get-AzureADUser  | select ObjectId, AccountEnabled`**

```
ObjectId                             AccountEnabled
--------                             --------------
xxx4037d27e015c               False
db5ccaa9xxx0740409e           True
```

[image]